# UINavigationController inside of a ContainerViewController popView's funky

Tags: ios, view, controller, navigation, containers

So I have a containerView Controller which acts like splitViewController basically.

I am trying to add a UINavigationController inside of the containerViewController, which works just fine.

I have created a UINavigationController in storyboards with a bunch of UIViewControllers connected to it, all hooked and linked together by 'push' segues. I take this NavigationController from the storyboard, stick it in my ContainerViewController via code. It then shows the NavigationController where it should, I can click the buttons, and the push animations happen ONLY inside of the NavigationController frame of the ContainerViewController.

However, if I call popViewController from code on my NavigationController, it will animate the entire ContainerViewController. Which I don't want, I want to it to only animate the NavigationController.

Does anyone know why it does that?

When you have a UINavigationController inside of a ContainerViewController, and then you can popViewController on the NavigationController, how do you make it so that it will animation only the UINavigationController and not the entire ContainerViewController it resides inside of?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem too. It was affecting my pushes as well. My work around was to use code instead of storyboard segues.

```
- (void) switchToView:(NSString *)identifier {
    UIViewController *target = [self getOrCreateViewController:identifier];
    [self switchToViewController:target identifier:identifier];
}

// If you need to interact with the VC before it is pushed break it into 2 step process
- (UIViewController *) getOrCreateViewController:(NSString *)identifier {
    NSArray *children = [self.viewControllers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"restorationIdentifier == %@", identifier, nil]];
    UIViewController *target = (children.count > 0 ? children[0] : [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier]);
    return target;
}

// For my use case, I always animate via push. Could modify this to pop/push as appropriate
- (void) switchToViewController:(UIViewController *)target identifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    [self setViewControllers:[self.viewControllers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"restorationIdentifier != %@", identifier, nil]] animated:NO];
    [self pushViewController:target animated:YES];

}
```

Kinda Fugly workaround I know... hoping I find a better answer (got here searching for one). :-)

Comment: Thanks! That works great. Hope this will be possible to do directly in the storyboard in the future, though. :-)